# Serving Ruby pages without Rails?

Tags: ruby

How would I go about displaying Ruby-generated dynamic pages without relying on a framework, such as Rails?

My intention is to serve Ruby .erb pages just as I would with .php files.

My server uses EngineX, which seems to play well together with Passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either write to the [Rack specification](http://rack.rubyforge.org/), or [use CGI](http://web.bilkent.edu.tr/WWW/hoohoo/cgi/index.html).